# Trouble Installing eth-brownie on Python 3.10.4 /mac os

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, pyyaml, brownie

I am trying to install eth-brownie on Python 3.10.4 using the command python3 -m pip install eth-brownie. However, I encountered an error during the installation process related to building the PyYAML package. The error message mentioned the attribute cython_sources causing the problem.

Here are the steps I have taken so far:

1. I ensured my Python environment is up-to-date by upgrading pip and setuptools.
2. I activated my virtual environment, but the issue still persists.
3. I checked for newer versions of eth-brownie that might be compatible with Python 3.10, but didn't find any.
4. I also tried installing an older version of PyYAML (5.3.1), but that didn't resolve the issue either.
5. I tried python 3.9.9

I would appreciate any help or advice on how to resolve this problem and successfully install eth-brownie on Python 3.10.4.

Comment: [Note that Brownie is no longer actively maintained(https://www.apelovesbrownie.org/). Here are some instructions to [migrate to Ape](https://academy.apeworx.io/articles/porting-brownie-to-ape).